# Problem when downloading source from overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I used a template of a journal to write a research paper and when I finished, I downloaded the source as a zip file and all the files are the original files of the journal's template, It does not show all the edits that I did, but when I download only the pdf, It works fine, when I download the source it shows the default journal template.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think it's better if you ask the Overleaf support button Help --> Contact us. They usually are very fast to reply.

Comment: There is an original PDF in the template, and that is what you are looking at. When you download "source" from Overleaf, it downloads the source, not the generated PDF. The source is everything that you see in the file tree on the left - which in this case includes that old PDF. If you're not sure about what is happening, please contact Overleaf support. I'm on the support team, and we don't mind answering questions about this at all.

Comment: @DanMacKinnon Thank you so much for your explanation, but now I want to know how to download the file as a latex document?
If I try to download it from the source I will get the latex document of the original template, and I want the latex document of the generated pdf.

Comment: @haya It sounds like you are looking at the wrong file - we can help you with specifics. Please reach out to support@overleaf.com with questions like this.